# How to match profile name to ant metadata profile name and vice versa?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, standard-objects, ant, custom-profile

Probably you know **System Administrator** profile, if you try to migrate change to object or field or page or application or class permissions for the profile and you try to retrieve it, you will get an error.

```
Entity of type 'Profile' named 'System Administrator' cannot be found
```

However, if you retrieve all profiles, you might find 'Admin.profile' which looks like matching to **System Administrator** profile.

On Profile Standard object there is no field exposed containing 'Admin'.

There is another profile called 'StandardAul.profile' amongst the ANT metadata files. I try hard to guess which profile it matches. Does it match to Standard Platform profile?

Is there any general way to match Salesforce profile name (visible on Web Interface, in Developer Console) and if you query for it by SOQL query:

```
[select Id, Name,  Description from Profile]
```

to ANT Metadata File name? Retrieving package.xml containing:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have finally found the solution.

While one of the possible point-and-click way is suggested by @user3375426 to create an outbound changeset and click add Profiles there (I have added here two screenshots, one for Professional Edition standard profiles mappings and another one for Enterprise Edition standard profile mappings),
[image: Profile name and API names for Professional Edition]
[image: Profile name and API names for Enterprise Edition]

another programmatic way is to query `Fullname` field on Profile using Tooling API.

In `Tooling API`, `name` field corresponds to the displayed name of Profile and `Fullname` field corresponds to Developer API Name of Profile. It is not possible to query by `Fullname` and query to retrieve `Fullname` are limited by 1 row, so it is not possible to get Developer API Name of every profile at once, however, it is possible to query one by one and retrieve their API name in such way.

For example, to find 'System Administrator` profile, the following query can be used

```
select id, name, fullName from Profile where name like '%admin%' limit 1
```

[image]

Also, we can verify that `StandardAul` is the `Standard Platform User` profile by making query

```
select id, name, fullName from Profile where name='Standard Platform User'
```

[image]

So the query results confirm that `StandardAul` is the `Standard Platform User` profile.

Just to summarize, the mappings for `Standard Profiles` in `Professional Edition`

```
Name                 API Name
Contract Manager     ContractManager
Marketing User       MarketingProfile
Solution Manager     SolutionManager
Read Only            ReadOnly
Standard User        Standard
System Administrator Admin
```

and the mappings for `Standard Profiles` in `Enterprise Edition`

```
Name                               API Name
Contract Manager                   ContractManager
Marketing User                     MarketingProfile
Solution Manager                   SolutionManager
Read Only                          ReadOnly
Standard User                      Standard
System Administrator               Admin
External Identity User             External Identity User
Guest License User                 Guest License User
High Volume Customer Portal User   High Volume Customer Portal User
Customer Community User            Customer Community User
Customer Community Plus User       Customer Community Plus User
Partner Community User             Partner Community User
Partner Community Login User       Partner Community Login User
Work.com Only User                 Work.com Only User
Chatter Only User                  Chatter Only User
Analytics Cloud Security User      Analytics Cloud Security User
Analytics Cloud Integration User   Analytics Cloud Integration User
Customer Community Login User      Customer Community Login User
Company Communities User           Company Communities User
Customer Community Plus Login User Customer Community Plus Login User
Standard Platform User             StandardAul
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To find out the API Name of the profile you can do the below steps:

Goto Setup --> Deploy --> Outbound Change Sets --> New --> Name it as Profiles --> Click save --> Under Profile Settings For Included Components --> Click Add Profiles button --> There you can get the list of all profiles with API Name.

You need to include the API name is ANT.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this works and helped me to find the ultimate answer to even use code for this

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file, there's a "label" attribute that tells you the corresponding UI name for the profile. The listMetadata utility call included in the Ant Migration Toolkit can provide a handy list of profiles, and it lists the labels and file names of all profiles in your org. See the sample build file that comes with the toolkit for the correct build syntax.

Comment: I don't see 'label' attribute when I try to retrieve profiles by 'retrieve' call. Does it come only if one makes "listMetadata' call?

Comment: I tried to use 'listMetadata' call but no luck:

FileName: profiles/StandardAul.profile
FullName/Id: StandardAul/00eE0000000z6DMIAY
Manageable State: null
Namespace Prefix: null
Created By (Name/Id): name/id
Last Modified By (Name/Id): name/id

Comment: I know I've parsed this out before somehow. I'll check my old archives and see if I still have a copy somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

StandardAul is Standard Platform license.

AFAIK, there is no label that matches the profile API name to Profile label - at least for the Standard profiles.

Good luck.

Sridhar

Comment: This answer just confirm that StandardAul is Standard Platform User profile but doesn't explain how to confirm this or how to find this

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I had the same issue retrieving system administrator xml file via ANT.

You should mention "Admin" as profile name.
your package.xml must be as followed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Location_Contact__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>Location_Contact__c-FSM Location Contact Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>Admin</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
  </types>
  <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem